# Applying measurement postulate to a continuous sum of eigenvectors (by analogy)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, probability, quantum-measurements

## [Measurement postulate:](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/be7c26e13550f3b3cc7f3f7a87f00d44_MIT8_04S16_LecNotes9.pdf)

> If we measure the Hermitian operator $\hat Q$ in the state $Ψ$, the possible
> outcomes for the measurement are the eigenvalues $q_1$, $q_2$, . . .. The probability $p_i$ to measure $q_i$ is given by
> $$p_i =
> |α_i
> |^2 $$
> where $Ψ(x) = \Sigma α_iψ_i(x)$

## Trying to apply it to a continuous sum of eigenstates:

I am trying to apply the measurement postulate to a continuous sum of eigenstates.

In the continuous sum
$$ \Psi(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(k)e^{ikx}dk$$

- $e^{ik_0x}$ plays the role of the eigenstate $ψ_i(x)$, for a particular $k_0$
- $\frac{\Phi (k_0) dk_0}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ plays the role of the coefficient $\alpha_i$
- the operator $\hat Q$, for example, is $\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} $
- the eigenvalue associated to $e^{ik_0 x}$ is $p_0$

As a result of this analogy, it should follow that the probability to measure $p_0$ in the state $Ψ$ is:
$$ \frac{|\Phi (k_0)|^2 |dk_0|^2}{{2\pi}} $$

I know however it is not correct because:

- of this weird $|dk_0|^2$,
- I know that $\int |\Phi(k)|^2dk = 1$ (from Parseval theorem) so the $2\pi$ looks suspicious

Edit:

I realize that if I've had taken the other Fourier transform (the one with the $2\pi$ in the exponential), the problem with the $2\pi$ would not have arised!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed your bullet points: In the continuous sum
$$ \Psi(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(k)e^{ikx}dk\,,$$

- $\frac{e^{ik_0x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ plays the role of the eigenstate $ψ_i(x)$ for a particular $k_0$, rather than just ${e^{ik_0x}}$, because the state needs to be *normalized* (in a sense to be discussed below)
- ${\Phi (k_0)}$ plays the role of the coefficient $\alpha_i$; we don't include the $dk$ for reasons explained below, and we've already moved off the factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$
- etc.

In moving from the discrete case to the continuous case, we can no longer talk about the probability of a getting a *particular* value upon measuring an observable.  Instead, we proceed as follows.

First of all, imagine we're measuring a continuous variable, say the position of a particle, but we can only measure the position to be in certain *regions* rather than at particular places (e.g., we lack perfect precision in our measurement. In other words, we have *bins* of size, say, $\Delta x$, so that we measure the position to be in $\dots,[-2\Delta x, -\Delta x]$, $[-\Delta x, 0]$, $[0, \Delta x]$, $[\Delta x, 2\Delta x],\dots$ and so on. Then, we can talk about the probability $P_j$ of measuring the position to be in bin $j$, i.e., in the bin $[j\Delta x, (j+1)\Delta x]$ so that the probability of finding the position being *anywhere* is of course 1, i.e.
$$
1= \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} P_j\,.
$$
Now, imagine that we want to make $\Delta x$ smaller and smaller, so that we are refining the precision of our measurement.  In fact, let's take the *limit* as $\Delta x\to0$.  How do we do this?  Well, write
$$
1= \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} {P_j}
=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{P\left(j\Delta x\leq x \leq(j+1)\Delta x\right)}{\Delta x}\Delta x\,.
$$
In order for the limit to make sense, the quantity $P_j/\Delta x$ should approach a finite limit $p(x)$ as $\Delta x \to0$.  We can then interpret $p(x)$ as a probability *per unit length*; that is, it is a *probability density*. The assumption that the limit exists is a *reasonable* assumption, because it essentially means that as long as $\Delta x$ is small enough, *doubling* the interval implies that we've doubled the probability that we can find the particle in the interval.

Now, accordingly, $p(x)\Delta x$ is approximately the probability that the particle is found between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$, and hence the probability of finding the particle *at* $x$ is zero. This is just the way that probability distributions for continuous variables work.  Finally, then, the sum above becomes the limit, i.e.
$$
1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)\,dx\,.
$$

Moving back to the quantum discussion, then, $|\Phi(k)|^2$ plays the role of a probability density function, and therefore $|\Phi(k)|^2dk$ is the probability that the momentum of the particle is measured to be in the interval $[k, k+dx]$.  We can verify that this makes sense at least mathematically buy using the (distributional) fact that
$$
\delta (k-k_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(k-k_0)x}}{2\pi}dk
$$
to verify that
$$
1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\Phi(k)|^2dk\,.
$$
(This is why $\sqrt{2\pi}$ is attached to the basis function: it is essentially the normalization factor of the basis function. Re the last comment in the OP about the factor of $2\pi$ in the exponent of the exponential: this would indeed render the normalization factors equal to 1.  However, note that
$$
\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx}e^{i2\pi k x} = (\hbar 2\pi k) e^{i2\pi k x}\,,
$$
so that the eigenvalue of the momentum operator is $p = \hbar 2\pi k$. This means that you have to re-interpret the value $k$: it is no longer the wave number; instead it is the reciprocal of the de Broglie wavelength, directly. This is fine, but it's not the convention normally chosen.)

Answer (score 4):

During the transition from finite to continuous basis $\nu_k$ of eigenstates we can't save the equation:
$$|\Psi\rangle =\sum|\nu_k\rangle \Psi_k$$
where $\Psi_k=\langle \nu_k|\Psi\rangle ,$ because transition is described by limit (usually we just split the part of value axis to finite number (N) of possible eigenvalues, coordinates for ex.):
$$N\rightarrow \infty$$
The consequences of this will be the infinite sum
$$\Psi=\sum |\nu_k\rangle \Psi_k$$
with senseless infinite value. The solution of this problem is increasing the eigenvector normalization
$$||\nu_k\rangle |^2= 1\rightarrow ||\nu_k\rangle |^2= 1/\epsilon$$
where $\epsilon$ is the minimal distance between allowed eigenvalues ($q_{k+1}-q_{k}=\Delta q$). It will cost us impossibility to realize the eigenstates in real life, because they can not be normalized to 1 in real life, that's why, for example the diffraction phenomena exists and photon wave package can't consist of only one clear monochromatic wave.

It's easier to write normalization by conjugate vectors:
$$|\nu_k\rangle ^{T*}=|\nu_k\rangle ^{+}=\langle \nu_k|\quad \text{so called bra-vector}$$
So, in general it's usually written like:
$$\langle \nu_n|\nu_m\rangle =\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\delta_{nm}$$
So, we have to make transition because of this renormalisation:
$$\Psi=\sum_{k=1}^N|\nu_k\rangle \Psi_k=\sum_{k=1}^N|\nu_k\rangle \langle \nu_k|\Psi\rangle \rightarrow \Psi=\sum_{k=1}^N|\nu_k\rangle \dfrac{\langle \nu_k|\Psi\rangle }{\langle \nu_k|\nu_k\rangle }=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^N|\nu_k\rangle \epsilon\langle \nu_k|\Psi\rangle $$
In the limit we easily obtain:
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N|\nu_k\rangle \epsilon\langle \nu_k|\Psi\rangle =\int |q\rangle dq \Psi(q)$$
In your cases we can choose the impulse basis:
$$|\Psi\rangle =\int |p\rangle dp \Psi(p)\rightarrow \langle q|\Psi\rangle =\Psi(q)=\int \langle q|p\rangle dp\Psi(p)=\int \Psi_p(q)dp\Psi(p)$$
The probability of measure $p_0$ is still $\Psi(p_0)$ but you can't anymore use
$$|\Psi\rangle =\sum|\nu_k\rangle \Psi_k$$